# Blue links issue on Gmail and iOS email clients

Tags: ios, colors, hyperlink, gmail, html-email

I'm building html emails and I know this is a known issue and I've tried many solutions to force address/phone/emails texts not to change the color and become a link on Gmail and ios. The only solution that partly works for me is to have my text inside  and  tags and style to have the font color I need. Here's my example:

```
...<tr><td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" align="center" style="color:#3C3D3F;line-height:24px;font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:15px 10px;font-size:12px;"><a href="" style="outline:none;color:#3C3D3F;cursor:initial;text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#3C3D3F;">128 Prinston St | Somewhere, CA 22314</span></a></td></tr>...
```

This works in sense of having the font color what I need, but I don't want to have this text as a link. As now I have to leave the href attribute empty which directs to a white page when clicking on the text from iOS default email.

So please suggest any working solution that would not need to have  tag in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Data detectors have become a real pain when crafting emails if you do not want that blue underline. I have several techniques I suggest you try.

Place the following in the `<head></head>` section of your email. If you already have a `<style></style>` section, add it there:

```
    <style>
    *[x-apple-data-detectors], .x-gmail-data-detectors, .x-gmail-data-detectors *, .aBn {
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
        cursor: default !important;
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
    }
    </style>
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, you can always do something like this around the areas that are being underlined:

```
<span style="color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; ">your content here</span>
```

One thing that might fix the issue is add META tags to the `<head></head>` area:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
```

If all else fails (and I have had issues where all else failed) I find that adding a non-printing character might help stop the data detector from detecting a url, phone number, address or date.

`&zwnj;`

A variation on this is usually effective:

```
gwally&zwnj;@&zwnj;stackoverflow&zwnj;.&zwnj;com
```

Good luck with ugly blue lines.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response and suggestions, I have tried them all but I'm still having the blue links. The problem here is that Gmail puts these texts inside <a> tag if you don't have it specified. So if you have the <span> with overriding styles, the <a> tag is being added inside that <span> and all your styles stop working.

Comment: @Lilit The issue with your html code. These techniques work. You don't post your code, so I can't tel you where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

How about appending a common style for links.

```
<style> a:link { color: #3C3D3F; } </style>
```

Code:

```
NSString *styledHTML =  [@"<style> a:link { color: #3C3D3F; } </style>" stringByAppendingString:originalHTMLString];
```

or

```
NSRange rOriginal    = [originalHTMLString rangeOfString:@"<tr>"];
NSString *styledHTML = [originalHTMLString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rOriginal withString:@"<tr><style> a:link { color: #dc3535; } </style>"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm building HTML emails, and not sure this code will work, where you suggest to write it?

Comment: append anywhere in your html.

Comment: That code breaks the templates. They are not shown at all on email clients. As for just specifying the color for links in general, I have that specified but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue but I sort it out by removing href attributes for anchor tag.

```
<td style="font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 18.6px; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 0.36px; color: #454D51 !important; text-decoration: none !important;">Sent by <span><a href="https://www.example.com"  style="font-weight: 700; text-decoration: underline !important; color: #454D51 !important;">example.com</a></span> <a style="color: #454D51 !important; text-decoration: none !important;">128 Prinston St | Somewhere, CA 22314</a>
```